# How to get all ubuntu programms back to fullscreen size after I'm not sure what I did?

Tags: 12.04, display, system-settings, popup-ads

I somehow managed to loose the ability of all my programs to resize on Ubuntu. Not sure what I did, but I thought I saw a popup open and being blocked in Firefox and after that all my programms opening like this screenshot:

[image: stuck in popup mode]

I can neither double click to expand nor close a program via the top bar because it's not there anymore.

**Question**:
Being a ubuntu beginner, what happened and more importantly, how do I switch back to normal programm size?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how to return your window bars, but holding ALT and right-clicking and dragging a corner of the window should resize the window.

Comment: I can drag but no resize.

Comment: Does it still act that way after a reboot?

Comment: Let's see. Brb. or not.

Comment: There's a window manager called Metacity. It might temporarily reduce the functionality/eyecandy done by Ubuntu, but you will have some sort of buttons. Press ALT+F2 and type in `metacity --replace`.

Comment: Ok. Reboot worked. Sorry for bothering. I was curious if it can be fixed "gently". @Parto: Make it an answer, so I can check.

Comment: In the future, you may want to know a few keyboard commands in case it happens again.  One good one is Alt-space will give you the system menu for the window, which can do several things, including close.  And instead of rebooting, you can usually use Alt-F2 to enter the command `gtk-window-decorator --replace`, if using Compiz, or `metacity --replace` if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reboot your system. That should do it.